# Textview Resize text When a screen is bigger than other

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I Would like to resize a textview, because some text are to small in tablets but in cellphone are normal.

Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.loading);
         TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
         txt.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
```

Comment: Generally you wouldn't do that in code, you'd have a layout override for tablets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the screen size

If you want the the display dimensions in pixels you can use [`getSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

If you're not in an `Activity` you can get the default `Display` via `WINDOW_SERVICE`:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Before `getSize` was introduced (in API level 13), you could use the `getWidth` and `getHeight` methods that are now deprecated:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

For the use case you're describing however a margin/padding in the layout seems more appropriate.

Now accordingly you can adjust your textView, by adding `weight` or something

Comment: I tried too sir.. But  don't know how to do it.. Appreciate if you can tell how to share Question.

Comment: At least you know how to copy and paste the link of the orignal post?

Answer (score 3):

Typically you would do this all with XML.  Then you can create a layout for larger screens.  You could for example, create a layout folder `layout-sw600dp` which would be used for screens with a smallest dimension of at least 600dp.

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers)